# Demasiada demora em consulta apenas em MySql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, query, tabela-banco-de-dados

Aqui na empresa possuímos bancos de dados PG e MySql, esses dois bancos ficam em rede e são idênticos tanto em estrutura como em dados, onde um "robô" realiza esse espelhamento entre eles de 10 em 10 min.

Até aí tudo bem... Acontece que agora que as bases estão ficando gigantes (atualmente 1170000 linhas em uma tabela), e chegou a um ponto em que o MySql não consegue executar mais consultas ou demora vários minutos. Os dois bancos são absolutamente os mesmos (tabelas, dados, estrutura, relacionamentos, etc). Quando realizamos uma consulta no Pg o retorno é rápido, não passa de 4 segundos, porém a mesma consulta que deveria retornar a mesma quantidade de dados o MySql não consegue atender.

Estou me referindo a uma consulta simples, sem Join, por exemplo. Como a seguinte:

```
SELECT idCdr, agente 
FROM `cdr` 
WHERE agente <> ''
GROUP BY agente
HAVING COUNT( agente ) > 1;
```

Essa mesma instrução, o PG me retorna em 3 segundos e o MySql leva alguns minutos. Já fiz testes na dashboard dos próprios bancos (phpMyAdmin e PgAdmin) e aconteceu mesma coisa.

Alguém tem ideia do que pode estar havendo?

Comment: Cara, você tem índices? Nestes casos onde as bases são imensas, deve-se ter um plano para minimizar este efeito de lentidão. Particionar, etc.

Comment: Tenho índices sim, em todas as tabelas. Consultas diretas ao índice específico são retornadas rapidamente. Agora uma consulta que varra toda a tabela (como acima), sem chance...

Comment: Esse SQL (exemplo) está errado, você está fazendo um *count* de um campo e agrupando o resultado por ele mesmo. Está assim no sistema ou vc apenas se confundiu ao compor a pergunta aqui no *SOpt*?

Comment: Verdade, não percebi. Mas esse foi um exemplo que criei apenas pra fazer a pergunta. Vou corrigir ali. Valeu Andrey.